# Grading tet mesh density in cgal polygon mesher

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I'm *still* trying to density control (grade) meshes in CGAL. Specifically tet-meshing a polygon surface (or multiple surface manifolds) that I simply load as OFF files. I can also load lists of selected faces or face nodes too.

But I can't seem to get to first base on this with the polygon tet-mesher. All I want to do is assign and enforce a mesh density/size at selected faces in the OFF file.

I *CAN* get some kinds of mesh density working by inserting 1-D features with volumetric data meshing, but for CAD and 3D printing purposes it *has to be computed* from an STL-like triangular surface manifold, so volume-based meshing is not do-able.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible in CGAL? It feels to me like it must be, and I'm just missing something obvious. 
I really hope someone can help here. FYI i'm mostly working with the Mesh3 example using v4.14.
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `Mesh_facet_criteria` and in particular this [constructor](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classCGAL_1_1Mesh__facet__criteria__3.html#a77f4b4b8646e0cf549cdce4f8684ec4d) where `SizingField` is where you can control the size. For locating the point wrt a face, you can use the AABB-tree function [`closest_point_and_primitive()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/classCGAL_1_1AABB__tree.html#a1b3ac9521fd7257f760deafff3743437).

Comment: Ok thx! have done that. I think it boils down to how to properly generate the SizingField. The basic example only shows a spherical analytical sizing field. But what I think I need is a  sizing field that is non-analytic (essentially defining sizes at each vertex or face of the surface).

Comment: Can I define sizes for all the vertices on the surface, and then compute 'generate' a 'sizing field' from that somehow with your code? I can do that in python but...
Apologies if I have missed something obvious.

Comment: I'm going to make a figure that better explains. I have thin and thick structures, but I want the thin structures to be less mesh-dense, and the thicker structures to be more dense, which is kind of 'opposite' what is normally done.

Comment: The sizing field API basically takes a point for the surface and must return the local sizing field. Using the AABB-tree  aforementioned function you can locate the point on the input triangle mesh and get the info about the size you want.

Comment: Thanks for info. I'm still having difficulty with a 'sizing field' how to specify. Here is an illustration:

https://i.imgur.com/oj5aPGw.png

I want to specify at verts different tet size, such that the *thin* part has larger elements (low density), and the *thick* region have smaller elements (high density).

It looks like all I need is to properly define the 'sizing field', but from the current examples can't figure it out. I can provide the vertex sizes as a list. Is it possible that someone could provide a brief code snippet? I have examined the docs and just can't figure it out. thx

Comment: Are you having issues with the AABB-tree part?